# Placing a lens in front of ultraviolet femtosecond laser with 10e38 J in pulse makes it a gun that fires microscopic black holes at speed of light?

Tags: optics, black-holes, photons

I calculated that in the focal spot of such a laser the critical energy density would be met.

Will these black holes really move at the speed of light, just as the the photons that made them? The conservation of momentum seems to give the speed of light here.

But if the black hole is a "matter-like" massive thing, how can it move at the speed of light?

Comment: Your black-hole gun here can't even be made using unobtanium.  I suspect your concept of "lens" violates 99.44% (plus 1 Internet for those who recognize that value :-) ) of all optics laws. Are you aware, by the way, that in general photons don't interact with each other? (sorry for being serious in that last sentence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Carl mentioned, such a contraption would be hard to build. However, I think it might work given a huge energy source and a *HUGE* lens.

The black hole would not move at light speed, though. Since you focused the light with a lens, the momenta of photons are not aligned. So the magnitude of the total momentum is smaller than the sum of magnitudes.

Also, the standard model and general relativity would probably break down at such energy densities. No one knows what would happen with a small black hole. It would probably decay instantly due to Hawking radiation.

A simpler example of light turning into matter is the [Schwinger](http://www.phys.uconn.edu/~dunne/dunne_schwinger.html) effect. Apparently, in electric fields larger than $E_{critical} \approx 10^{16} V/cm$ photons will collide with each other and produce an electron/positron pair and those do not move with the speed of light.